# Electron application cannot resolve any node module that is added to webpack externals

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to build an Electron application using Vue.js.
I am using webpack-dev-server to run the electron app in development mode.

In the webpack config I am adding all my node_modules to the externals array since I do not want them to be bundled.

The webpack development server gets started successfully without any error and the application is also launched as expected but I get the following error in the console.

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'frappejs'`.
Note: This is not the only module that cannot be resolved. All the modules that I have added to the webpack externals arrays could not be resolved.

If I do not add them to the externals array, the node_modules are detected and the above error disappears.

Another thing that I have noticed is that if I replace
`const frappe = require('frappejs');` with
`const frappe = require('../../node_modules/frappejs');`
The error disappers in this case as well when I am explicitly pointing to the node_modules directory.

What maybe the reason for this behaviour?

**config.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

// plugins
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsWebpackPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const { getAppConfig, resolveAppDir } = require('./utils');
const appDependencies = require(resolveAppDir('./package.json')).dependencies;
const frappeDependencies = require(resolveAppDir('./node_modules/frappejs/package.json')).dependencies;
// const frappeDependencies = require('../package.json').dependencies;
let getConfig, getElectronMainConfig;

function makeConfig() {
  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  process.env.ELECTRON = 'true';
  const isElectron = process.env.ELECTRON === 'true';  
  const isMonoRepo = process.env.MONO_REPO === 'true';

  const whiteListedModules = ['vue'];
  const allDependencies = Object.assign(frappeDependencies, appDependencies);
  const externals = Object.keys(allDependencies).filter(d => !whiteListedModules.includes(d));

  getConfig = function getConfig() {
    const appConfig = getAppConfig();
    const config = {
      mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
      context: resolveAppDir(),
      entry: isElectron ? appConfig.electron.entry : appConfig.dev.entry,
      externals: isElectron ? externals : undefined,
      target: isElectron ? 'electron-renderer' : 'web',
      output: {
        path: isElectron ? resolveAppDir('./dist/electron') : resolveAppDir('./dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        // publicPath: appConfig.dev.assetsPublicPath,
        libraryTarget: isElectron ? 'commonjs2' : undefined
      },
      devtool: !isProduction ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : '',
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: file => (
              /node_modules/.test(file) &&
              !/\.vue\.js/.test(file)
            )
          },
          {
            test: /\.node$/,
            use: 'node-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader'
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
              'file-loader'
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.css', '.node'],
        alias: {
          'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
          'deepmerge$': 'deepmerge/dist/umd.js',
          '@': appConfig.dev.srcDir ? resolveAppDir(appConfig.dev.srcDir) : null
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(Object.assign({
          'process.env': appConfig.dev.env,
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': isProduction ? '"production"' : '"development"',
          'process.env.ELECTRON': JSON.stringify(process.env.ELECTRON)
        }, !isProduction ? {
          '__static': `"${resolveAppDir(appConfig.staticPath).replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')}"`
        } : {})),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: resolveAppDir(appConfig.dev.entryHtml),
          nodeModules: !isProduction
            ? isMonoRepo ? resolveAppDir('../../node_modules') : resolveAppDir('./node_modules')
            : false
        }),
        new CaseSensitivePathsWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin({
          compilationSuccessInfo: {
            messages: [`FrappeJS server started at http://${appConfig.dev.devServerHost}:${appConfig.dev.devServerPort}`],
          },
        }),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        isProduction ? new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            from: resolveAppDir(appConfig.staticPath),
            to: resolveAppDir('./dist/electron/static'),
            ignore: ['.*']
          }
        ]) : null,
        // isProduction ? new BabiliWebpackPlugin() : null,
        // isProduction ? new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true }) : null,
      ].filter(Boolean),
      optimization: {
        noEmitOnErrors: false
      },
      devServer: {
        // contentBase: './dist', // dist path is directly configured in express
        hot: true,
        quiet: true
      },
      node: {
        // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
        // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
        setImmediate: false,
        // process is injected via DefinePlugin, although some 3rd party
        // libraries may require a mock to work properly (#934)
        process: 'mock',
        // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
        // that does not make sense for the client
        dgram: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        child_process: 'empty'
      }
    }
    return config;
  }

  getElectronMainConfig = function getElectronMainConfig() {
    const appConfig = getAppConfig();
    return {
      entry: {
        main: resolveAppDir(appConfig.electron.paths.main)
      },
      externals: externals,
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
          },
          {
            test: /\.node$/,
            use: 'node-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      node: {
        __dirname: !isProduction,
        __filename: !isProduction
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        path: resolveAppDir('./dist/electron')
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        // isProduction && new BabiliWebpackPlugin(),
        isProduction && new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        })
      ].filter(Boolean),
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.node']
      },
      target: 'electron-main'
    }
  }
}

makeConfig();

module.exports = {
  getConfig,
  getElectronMainConfig
};
```

Note: the resolveAppDir function returns the cwd path concatenated with the parameter passed.